# How to force Illustrator to accurately trace the actual pixels?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector-graphics, bitmaps

I’m trying trace and convert a bitmap to a vector image, but I need Illustrator to actually trace the actual pixels, not smooth them out.

I’ve tried various settings with “Live Trace,” but the result is always curves and weird shapes. I need the actual pixels in vector (square corners, straight lines). How do I do that?

Comment: Do you have an example area of the image you're trying to trace?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a pixel-perfect trace in Flash CS5 or 6 (Modify-> Trace bitmap, with maximum settings: minimum area 1 pixel, corner threshold "few corners" and curve fit "pixels") and export it from Flash in .fxg format, which you can then import to Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this GD.SE answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/9395/8708), you can do this using the "Create Object Mosaic" function. Here's a demonstration using [this 16 x 16 pixel graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRol2.gif):

[[image: Convert pixel art to vector using Illustrator]

If you'd like a more automated solution, you could instead use a free and open source tool called [pixel2svg](http://florian-berger.de/en/software/pixel2svg/). That tool does not support alpha transparency but a [slight modification](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/58020/8708) to the source code will fix that. [cyChop's fork](https://github.com/cyChop/pixel2svg-fork) specifically addresses that.